# flush() doesn't update embed documents

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, embed, flush

I have this classes:

```
class Country
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    protected $iso;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\EmbedOne(targetDocument="Localstring")
     */
    protected $name;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->name = new Localstring();
    }
}

class Localstring
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Hash
     */
    private $location = array();
}
```

I want to update every country with a new translation:

```
$dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')
    ->getManager();

foreach ($json as $iso => $name) {
    $country = $dm->getRepository('ExampleCountryBundle:Country')->findOneByIso($iso);

    $localstring_name = $country->getName();
    $localstring_name->addTranslation('es_ES', $name);

    $dm->flush();
}
```

If I print one object just before flushing it prints correctly:

```
Example\CountryBundle\Document\Country Object ( [id:protected] => 541fe9c678f965b321241121 [iso:protected] => AF [name:protected] => Example\CountryBundle\Document\Localstring Object ( [id:Example\CountryBundle\Document\Localstring:private] => 541fe9c678f965b321241122 [location:Example\CountryBundle\Document\Localstring:private] => Array ( [en_EN] => Afghanistan [es_ES] => Afganistán ) ) )
```

But on database it doesn't updates. I tried updating $iso and it works. Why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to persist your object. `flush()` just pushes into DB your changes that were registered by `persist()` (called with your object in argument). It needs to be here because you doesn't change your document. You just added the translation. This functionality covered by Translatable extension and doesn't tell to the Doctrine that your object was modified. And when Doctrine will prepare the changelist for query it will not find changes and will not create the query.

Your code should look like this:

```
$dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')
    ->getManager();

foreach ($json as $iso => $name) {
    $country = $dm->getRepository('ExampleCountryBundle:Country')->findOneByIso($iso);

    $localstring_name = $country->getName();
    $localstring_name->addTranslation('es_ES', $name);

    $dm->persist($country);
}
$dm->flush();
```

Comment: These objects exists on database before, this is an update action. DoctrineMongoDB documentation says `persist()` call it's no needed (http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html#updating-an-object). Anyway I tried with your code and it doesn't works.

Comment: As you can see in the page (from your link)
`Recall that this method simply tells Doctrine to manage or "watch" the $product object`. Your translation extension doesn't manage this "watching". And therefore it doesn't tell to Doctrine that your object was updated.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the persist your object!

try this at the end of your foreach: `$dm->persist($your_object);`

and outside form foreach put the `$dm->flush();`

Comment: You answered with the same answer as I did earlier. I think that it is not good to double answers;-)